# sum of a infinite series involving sine function

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was solving a electrostatic problem which involved solving Laplace equation in two dimension. The solution is (in the form of Fourier sine series):

$$V(x,y)= \frac{4V_0}{\pi}  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{2n-1}exp(-(2n-1)\pi \frac xa)\sin ((2n-1)\pi \frac ya)$$

Now it asked to find the surface charger density which can be found by partial differentiating $V$ with respect to $x$ at $x=0$. The result is :

$$\sigma =\epsilon_0 \frac{ 4V_0}{a} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sin ((2n-1)\pi \frac ya)$$

The answer is given as:

$$\sigma =\epsilon_0 \frac{ 2V_0}{a}\frac{1}{\sin (\pi \frac ya)}$$

I tried summing the series by using the formula:

$$Sum = \frac{\sin(\frac{a_1 + a_n}{2} )\sin(\frac{nd}{2})}{\sin(\frac d2)}$$
Here $a_n$ is the arthematic progression with common difference $d$.

I substituted the values to find the sum of required series till $n^{th}$ term then tried taking the $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ but couldn't find the limit.

$$Sum = \frac{\sin^2(n\pi \frac ya)}{\sin(\pi \frac ya)}$$

Is there any other way to find the sum of this series and where am I going wrong?

Edit: I found out that the sum I require corresponds to the sum given by dirichlet regularisation but how does this thing entered into here?

Comment: It looks like you want the [Dirichlet regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_regularization#Relation_to_Dirichlet_series); see [Wolfram's ouput](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+sin%28%282n-1%29pi*y%2Fa%29+from+n%3D1+to+infinity).

Comment: You produced a divergent series by commuting the derivative past the summation. Simplest is to evaluate your first sum for $V$ directly- by converting $\sin$ into complex exponential form and using Feynman's trick, then differentiate the result. This yields an unambiguous answer. Alternatively you can try to 'regularize' the divergent series but note that the suggested Dirichlet regularization amounts to appending a term $e^{-nt}$ into the sum which just reproduces a sum similar to your original- so rather than evaluating that I suggest evaluating your first expression